# How can I execute all methods if I get exception in the first method?

Tags: c#, exception, c#-4.0, try-catch

I have 2 methods: `method1()` and `method2()`.
Each method can create exception (`WebException`).
I have `methodMain()` in this method I execute the first method is `method1()` and them I execute `method2()`.
For example:

```
public void methodMain()
{
    ...
    try
    {
        method1();
        method2();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        //do something
    }
    ...
}
```

If I get exception from `method1()` the `method2()` doesn't executed.

How can I execute all methods if I get exception in the first method?

I came up with solution:

```
public void methodMain()
{
    ...
    try
    {
        method1();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        //do something
    }
    ...
    try
    {
        method2();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        //do something
    }
    ...
}
```

I think my solution is not good and not beautiful.

Again my question: How can I execute all methods if I get exception in the first method?

Comment: Put this Try/Catch blocks inside Your methods.

Comment: I don't see anything ugly about your solution :)

Comment: if you want to treat and handle each method separately, then you have to use multiple `try-catch` blocks.

Comment: ah, the good old days of `on error resume next`... I'm so glad they are over :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled excuse me, what do you mean by : 'on error resume next'?

Comment: Nothing good, this was VB way of error handling before the .Net framework. just be glad you don't have to use this s**t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap those methods in a delegate and execute it. You can add any number of methods to the `actions` array and execute in a loop.

```
public void methodMain()
{
    Action[] actions = new Action[]
    {
       method1,
       method2
    };

    foreach(var method in actions)
    {
        try
        {
            method();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think your solution is ok. May be I will take this solution.

Comment: I love how creative this solution is.  And it removes the code repetition.

Comment: It makes some pretty big assumptions about the signatures of the methods though, (although I suppose some of that can be handled with lambdas wrapping the actual methods).

Comment: @JonEgerton I answered based on OP's code which is compatible with `Action` lambda. No assumption here.

Comment: I know - just saying - I'd like to hope the the OPs code was a simplification, and not actual production code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options; either you separate the calls to `method1` and `method2` in separate `try-catch` blocks or you move the `try-catch` to the inside of both methods.

Which option is best depends on what does methods do and where they are called. If you only want to handle/swallow exceptions in this `methodMain`-method then this is the right solution. However if you want to ignore the exceptions everywhere, then I suggest you move the `try-catch` blocks to the inside of both methods.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I think that I will separate try-catch blocks or I will use the solution by Sriram Sakthivel